# Excluded Custom Taxonomy Term Posts Displaying in loop

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, terms

I created a custom post type called "careers" with a custom post type taxonomy called "careers_categories". Within this taxonomy I have a term called "featured". My intent is to exclude all post within the loop that contain the term "featured" with a term ID of 60, the terms will be displayed in the archive-careers.php and I am using [ISOTOPE PLUGIN](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to create a filter for the accompanying posts.I would also like to have the "featured" post display in a hero at the top of the page. The terms are displayed as links and the filtering works with the accompanying post in the query below. The "featured" term is not displaying as a link but the post associated with the term is still displaying. It is important to note that the post that contains the term "featured" can also have the another term like "graphic_design" and I would like them to be displayed under the secondary term. please see my code below:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="fl-content col-lg-12">

            <?php $terms =
            get_terms( array(
                    'taxonomy'   => 'careers_categories',
                    'hide_empty' => true,
                            'exclude'=> '60',
            ));?>


            <div class="hero">
                <?php if( has_term('', 'featured') ){
                    the_title();
                }?>

            </div>
            <?php if( $terms ) {
            ?>
            <ul id="my-category" class="filter clearfix">
                <li><a href="#" class="active" data-filter="*"><span>All</span></a></li>
                <?php foreach( $terms as $term ){
                    echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.$term->slug'><span>$term->name</span></a></li>";
                } ?>
            </ul>
            <?php }


                        if( have_posts() ) { ?>
            <div id="cpt-wrap" class="clearfix filterable-cpt  grid" data-isotope='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "layoutMode": "fitRows" }'>
                <div class="cpt-content">




                    <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>



                    <?php $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'careers_categories' ); ?>

                    <?php
                    global $post; ?>
                    <article class="grid-item cpt-item <?php if( $terms ) foreach ( $terms as $term ) { echo $term->slug.' '; }; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <?php
                                if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
                                echo the_post_thumbnail();
                                } ?>
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        </a>
                    </article>


                    <?php endwhile; ?>



                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 


<?php get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below methods:

1. Try by adding term ID in array like this `'exclude'=> '60'` in array
2. If this is not working you can try with below `WP_Query` loop:

```
 $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'careers',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'careers_categories',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => array( 60),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I have done so in the above example that is why the term is not displaying. But the posts associated with the term is displaying.

Comment: Then may be you have selected two terms/categories in backend. Please make sure

Comment: Yes like i stated "It is important to note that the post that contains the term "featured" can also have the another term like "graphic_design" and I would like them to be displayed under the secondary" The post only has the featured term on the backend.

Comment: You have to write the two loop then or use `WP_Query` at  inside that write `get_term()` and check

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am a little confused to be honest. `$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'news_categories'  );` is still giving me the 'featured' posts. A little more clarification will be a big help, I appreciate it.